# Android, Gradle, Kotlin-dsl, multi-module, centralize android blocks for application and library, as well as dependencies?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-multi-module

Gradle - 8.2.1, AGP - 8.0.2, Kotlin - 1.9.0

buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:8.0.2")
}
```

gradle/support/common-app-config.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    ...
}
android {
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":feature-one"))
    implementation(project(":feature-two"))
    ...
}
```

Similarly, gradle/support/common-lib-config.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    ...
}
android {
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":platform"))
    ...
}
```

Also, gradle/support/common-dependencies.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx", "lifecycle", "navigation"... )
    /** You get the gist of this block **/
    ...
}
```

Is there a clean approach to centralizing the android {} blocks for application and library, separately is still fine, as well as dependencies {} block for re-use ?

So far, app/build.gradle.kts

```
apply {
    from(file("${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/support/common-app-config.gradle.kts"))
}
```

fails with "Unresolved reference : android", despite declaring the "com.android.application" plugin in the common-app-config.gradle.kts file.

Comment: Why have you put the convention plugins in the `gradle/support/` directory? Usually they go in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/`

Comment: Version-catalogs appear to be visible only to outer build-script files - `./build.gradle.kts`, `./settings.gradle.kts`, `./buildSrc/**.gradle.kts`, ( Convention plugins folder, let's say ) `./gradle/support/**.gradle.kts`, but version-catalogs are not visible inside the convention plugins folders `./gradle/support/src/main/kotlin/*`, primarily because kotlin-dsl extract plugins {} block from `./gradle/support/src/main/kotlin/**.gradle.kts` files into `./gradle/support/build/kotlin-dsl/plugins-blocks/extracted/**.gradle.kts`, and that's where version-catalogs aren't resolving ?

Comment: Wants to implement similar functionality in my project too

Comment: I'm interested in this topic too. What I'm doing is to check in the project if has the app or the library plugin with project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application"), and depending on that applying a gradle script file or another (In this gradle file I can apply the library or application plugins to access the android). But in the end I need to have the android part duplicated.

In Groovy you can do this very easily.